# Julia memory reuse with multiple function outputs

Tags: memory-management, julia

You can reuse array memory as follows

```
> a=[1,2,3];b=a;a=[1,2,3];is(a,b)
false

> a=[1,2,3];b=a;a.=[1,2,3];is(a,b)
true
```

This is only necessary, as far as I can tell, when assigning the entire array.  When assigning a subset, you will always use the existing array whether using `.=` or `=`.

I ran into a problem with this when using functions with multiple outputs.  Example:

```
> f = () -> ([1,2,3],[4,5,6]);
> a, = f()
([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

> a, .= f()
 ERROR: syntax: invalid identifier name ".="

> (a,) .= f()
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching broadcast!(::Base.#identity,::Tuple{Array{Int64,1}}, ::Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}})
Closest candidates are:
  broadcast!{nargs}(::Any, ::AbstractArray{T,N}, ::Any...) at broadcast.jl:169
  broadcast!(::Base.#identity, ::AbstractArray{T,N}, ::Number) at broadcast.jl:19
  broadcast!{T,S,N}(::Base.#identity, ::AbstractArray{T,N}, ::AbstractArray{S,N}) at broadcast.jl:23
```

Is there a way to do this without having to throw away `a` at each call?

Comment: this seems like an unusual thing to do if you want to reuse allocated memory. could you instead write `f()` as a mutating function, e.g. `f!(a, b) = a .= b` or something similar? otherwise, based on what you have written, it seems like Julia expects you to preallocate the correct output `(a,b)`. is that a feasible alternative for you?

Comment: In this situation, since I wrote the function, it wouldn't be a big deal to create another version that only returns one value or mutates in place.  It's slightly inconvenient, but more importantly, what if I was using a package?  The only thing I can think of would be to wrap the function so that it only returns one value, but the underlying function would have allocated the memory, so there would be no point.

Comment: What's wrong with `a .= f()[1]`?

Comment: You know, I think that's the answer.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a .= f()[1]
```

does the trick. However, I should note that this does *not* avoid allocating memory for the output array (as was perhaps your intention?); it's still allocated, and then eventually garbage collected after copying its contents to `a`. The only way to do that is to pass in `a` as a parameter to a mutating `f!` variant of `f`.

I don't think there is nice syntax to assign both outputs in place. You can store the result of `f()` in a temporary (this store involves no copying, since it just aliases the memory returned by `f()`):

```
tmp = f()
a .= tmp[1]
b .= tmp[2]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  Although, I may have had it muddled in my head, which is why I couldn't come up with the obvious answer.  I feel like I should make this a little harder.  How would you assign both outputs in place?

Comment: I would do it in the "obvious" way, which I have added to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't fully understand.  I didn't realize the returned results alias the memory returned by f().